# Chrome giving error "Extra content at the end of the document" when adding another <h:column>

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have the following JSF table:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>List</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<h1>List</h1>

    <h:form>

        <h:dataTable value="#{myBean.workflows}" var="item">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                #{item.id}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                #{item.name}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:link outcome="edit" value="Edit">
                    <f:param name="myId" value="#{item.id}"/>
                </h:link>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:link outcome="run" value="Run">
                    <f:param name="myId" value="#{item.id}"/>
                </h:link>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                 <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{myBean.doDelete}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

The following part:

```xml
    <h:column>
         <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{myBean.doDelete}" />
    </h:column>
```

is causing `"error on line 361 at column 9: Extra content at the end of the document"` error to show up in Chrome above the table. At the same time, an exception is shown in the server log saying: "Unable to generate Facelets error page as the response has already been committed".

Why is the extra `<h:column>` causing this error?

**UPDATE:** It appears that the error will be thrown whenever there are more than two components (for example three `h:link` components).

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this issue is already known http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1880 You might want to try their testcase and/or another comment.

Comment: FYI, I quickly copied your example to a local Facelet here, adding only htlm -> h:body -> h:form to the top, but did not get to see the error on Chrome 11/OS X/JBoss AS 6. Maybe you should post your complete Facelet and some extra details as which server you're using at the JIRA issue BalusC referred to?

Comment: Btw, to be double sure, what happens when you open the same page with say Safari or Firefox?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I put the entire Facelet now. I'm running it on Glassfish 3.1. If I open the same page in Firefox, it is displayed fine.

Comment: GF 3.1 with default bundled Mojarra? What Mojarra version is printed in INFO log? What Chrome version do you see in *Options > About*? What OS are you using?

Comment: BalusC, I am using Mojarra 2.1.0 (FCS 2.1.0-b11), Chrome 11.0.696.71, on NetOS (a customized CentOS). I've also noticed that this error happens whenever there are more than two components (see my update to he original post). Likewise, even though Firefox will not actually show the error on the GUI, an exception will be shown in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that this happens only when there's a rendering exception, but it's been too late for Facelets to change the response into a fullworthy HTTP 500 error page. It's too late because a part of the response has already been committed, which is a point of no return. This explains the "Unable to generate Facelets error page as the response has already been committed" error.

Chrome will apparently display "Extra content at the end of the document" when the resulting HTML/XML is malformed. Indeed, Facelets has abruptly stopped rendering the HTML due to the exception.

To fix the problem you should look back in the server logs for the **real** exception which caused Facelets to stop rendering the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the effort BalusC. In fact the stacktrace in server.log is very similar to the one posted in the Jira issue. There are no other exceptions in the log except `PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed`, so if you have any tips on how I could find the root cause, that would be great.

Comment: Ah yes, you get the same exception as in issue 1880. If it is true what the exception says, I'd somehow ensure that the session is been created before the response is committed. E.g. by calling `request.getSession()` before `chain.doFilter(req, res)` in a filter. Give it a try, even though it's just for test.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I actually called `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);` in a `@PostConstruct` method of the managed bean, and this fixed the issue. I'm not sure if it's an OK solution though. Is this a bug in the implementation or?

Comment: This is definitely a bug in the implementation. It should have created the session long before the render once it knows that a state needs to be saved at some point. I have however never seen it by myself, but I have not really used 2.1.0 intensively. After 2.0.5 we went to 2.1.1 directly.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your xhtml:

f:view

and close it at the end of you form or just add it and close it before/after body tags.

Comment: OP is using Facelets, not JSP. So `<f:view>` is not mandatory.